# Cannot output cursor location to debug string (WIN32)

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

For some reason, when I am trying to output the location of the mouse cursor in a given WIN32 window using the following code:

```
//Global Variable
POINT cursorLocation;

// Win32 Windowing subsystem code redacted

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

cursorLocation.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
cursorLocation.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

 switch(message){
   case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
   // mouse movement handle
   OutputDebugString(cursorLocation.x + "," + cursorLocation.y);
   OutputDebugString("\n");
   // WM_MOUSEMOVE break
   break;
 }
}
```

Now when I run the program and move the mouse, the following text is logged to the console:

> a smaller data type has caused a loss of data.
>    If this was intentional, you should mask the source of the cast with the appropriate bitmask.
>   For example: char c = (i & 0xFF);
>   Changing the code in this way will not affect the quality of the resulting optimized code.

I even tried typecasting the variables passed to `OutputDebugString` to a `LONG`, because that is the type of the variables in the `POINT` class and there was no difference.

Does anyone know how to have the values passed through the `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM` to the debug console?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a string concatenation, but adding `.x` and `.y` to pointer to `","`:

```
cursorLocation.x + "," + cursorLocation.y
```

Instead, try e.g.:

```
char s[256];
sprintf_s(s, "%d,%d", cursorLocation.x, cursorLocation.y);
OutputDebugStringA(s); // added 'A' after @IInspectable's comment, but
                       // using UNICODE and wchar_t might be better indeed
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks.  I've been switching back and forth between languages and didn't notice that as an issue.

Comment: @xec86: If it worked for you, you are using the wrong compiler settings. There is absolutely, positively no reason whatsoever to use ANSI character encoding. All Windows code should be written using Unicode, by calling the wide character version of all APIs that consume or produce strings, switching from `char` to `wchar_t`, and prepending all string literals with an `L`. Your compiler will point you to the locations that need attention, once you define the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbols on the command line (`/DUNICODE /D_UNICODE`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was wondering why the prepended L's that I had in some code snippets that I had saved were not working.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I enforced ANSI for the sake of correctness. Although "_there is absolutely, positively no reason whatsoever to use ANSI_" sounds a bit too strong for me, I agree that UNICODE is often a better option.

Comment: @AlexD: That native character encoding of Windows is UTF-16LE. There really is absolutely, positively no reason whatsoever to waste clock cycles converting from ANSI to UTF-16 and back for every API call. There is nothing to be gained from using ANSI encoding (outside of interfacing with legacy code).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.  in the end I changed my Project defaults to use the unicode language set and then appended "L" to all strings and then used wchar_t s[256] for the variable and then output it with the unicode friendly swprintf_s(s, L"%d,%d\n", cursorLocation.x, cursorLocation.y); all is working fine and apparently more efficiently as well.

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation doesn't work with integers.
Try using `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream out_stream;
out_stream << cursorLocation.x << ", " << cursorLocation.y;
OuputDebugString(out_stream.str().c_str());
```